# realpath() in my env doesn't like NULL as second argument?

Tags: c, linux, realpath

I'm on a linux box and `/proc/self/exe` does seem to be supported:

- `ls -l /proc/self/exe` shows that it's linked to `/usr/bin/ls` at the moment I run the command
- `realpath /proc/self/exe` prints out `/usr/bin/realpath` as expected
- both commands exit with status `0`

But:

```
if (NULL == realpath("/proc/self/exe", NULL))
{
  printf("this prints unexpectedly, %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

At this point, `errno` is `22` and I see `Invalid argument`. Why? Or -- how does one figure out why?

Comment: What is your `glibc` version?

Comment: `ldd --version` says `ldd (GNU libc) 2.20`

Comment: Well, you should check you glibc package version (which disto is it?). But 2.2 is lower than 2.3, so my answer is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior would occur on `glibc` versions below 2.3 as stated in [`man realpath`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html):

> ERRORS
>   ............
>          EINVAL - `path` is `NULL`.  (In glibc versions before 2.3, this error is
>                 also returned if `resolved_path` is `NULL`.)